# Android getting multiline strings from XML problems

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to print a text which is fetched from the server. What is the best way to escape all special characters and print safely? 
Because the string which is fetched from the server is entered by user an stores it on database. So there is a possibility use `<?php ?>` , `&` etc which may cause errors. I have tried `&lt; &gt;` which solved this problem. 
But when setText() the string to an EditText the string gets truncated after `&`

So I need a best solution in which the text entered by the user will save safely in the database and retrieve the multi-line string with special characters safely.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Interesting question: are you using XML and the SAX parser? If so, Dinesh's answer pretty much applies. However, if you are using PHP, is there a reason why you aren't using JSON?

Comment: I am using XML Parser. I have almost done using XMl and it is hard to recode it in JSON

Answer (score 0):

I think  you should use **StringBuilder** instead of simply reading the text from XML.

Follow these steps :

1) For each new tag in XML (in startElement) , create a String builder

2) Append the text to same StringBuilder in reading from Character method.

3) At last, assign that StringBuider to some String at the End of the tag (in EndElement).

Hope this will give you some idea to solve the problem .

Try ...!!!

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think this will solve the problem. But can you post some useful codes or links?

Answer (score 0):

Anyways the problem solved by using `URLDecode.decode()` at the app and `urldecode(),stripslashes()` at the server side.

Dont know whether this is the perfect solution, but it worked for me.